# How to add suggestion list to JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing

How to add suggestion list ( when user type part of some word to suggest list of all tokens which starts with that part, something like intellisense in Eclipse ) to JEditorPane ? I have implemented method which returns ArrayList of strings but how to show that ?

Comment: See this example http://www.inetsoftware.de/other-products/jortho/sample (right click to the wrongly words and you will oabtain suggestions). You can download source code of jortho library and you can discover how it works

Answer (score 1):

add them to a JList and show the list in a JPopupMenu

Answer (score 1):

javax.swing.JPopupMenu may help u...

for every keyReleasedEvent pass the substring to your method..

for each suggested string javax.swing.AbstractAction should be created..

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use the open source [Jide common layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm), particularly the [AutoCompletion](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/AutoCompletion.html) helper class.  [image: Autocompletion text/jcombobox] [image: Autocompletion text/jcombobox]

It works with a lot of swing components, with or without a list of possibilities being shown.  Highly recommended.